# Can't create insert cascade in ActiveAndroid library

Tags: java, android, orm, activeandroid

I use ActiveAndroid library in my project. In the model I have the following parameters:

```
onDelete = Column.ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE, onUpdate = Column.ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE
```

But it's impossible to find Insert cascade or something else.
My models has many relations and I need to save them all:

```
for (Transaction transaction : shoppingSession.getTransactionList()) {
                transaction.setShoppingSession(shoppingSession);
                TransactionDao.save(transaction);
            }
public static Transaction save(Transaction transaction){
        if (null != transaction.getTransactionItem().getItemInfo()){
            transaction.getTransactionItem().getItemInfo().save();
        }
        if (null != transaction.getTransactionItem().save()){
            transaction.getTransactionItem().save();
        }
        transaction.save();
        return transaction;
    }
```

It is inconvenient. I hope the library will be able to save all this in the relevant tables.

How can I implement it?

Thanks.